# C++ Why can't I do arithmetic with, or cast variables in a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, casting

I have a game where I want to calculate the wins and losses of a player playing rock paper scissors against the computer (C++'s random number function). In order to keep track of the players wins, losses, and ties against the computer, I created this structure (which is global):

```
struct human{
    short wins = 0;
    short losses = 0;
    short ties = 0;
};
```

The problem occurs when I try to do math with one of the `short` variables in the structure:

```
int main(){
    short totalPlays = 1;
    float winsPerc;
    outcome(totalPlays, winsPerc);
}
void outcome(short totalPlays, float& winsPerc){
    winsPerc = (static_cast<float>(human.wins) / static_cast<float>(totalPlays))* 100;
}
```

In these two functions I'm trying to calculate the percentage of wins the player has. However, my compiler seems to be interpreting the `human` part of the `human.wins` variable as a type. So of course I tried changing `human.wins` to `short human.wins` to no avail.  After that the compiler only said that the type of `short` was unexpected. As this is so vague I really haven't a clue what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstood what `struct`s are. You are treating your `struct human` as an object with data that you can do things with, but it's not; it's a *type*, just like a class. In fact, it *is* a class.

Randomly adding the keyword `short` before utterances of its members is not going to accomplish much of anything! (Your "of course" clause is nonsensical, I'm afraid.)

You must instantiate the type before you can do things with it. In your case there's an easy shorthand:

```
struct {
    short wins = 0;
    short losses = 0;
    short ties = 0;
} human;
```

Now this is an unnamed `struct` type definition, immediately instantiated as `human`.

Something that may be contributing to your confusion is the use of yet another shorthand: those inline member initialisers (which have only been valid syntax for a small handful of years). They say that, whenever an object of this type is instantiated, all of its members will be initialised to `0`. It might be more obvious if your code looked like this:

```
struct human_t {
    short wins;
    short losses;
    short ties;
};

human_t human = {0, 0, 0};
```

Though the previous example is probably fine as long as your audience understands modern C++.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Now I know why everyone was downvoting my question. I did look for an answer to this question through Google before coming here, though. :\